# pandas determine column labels that contribute to non-zero values in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the dataframe shown below, I want to do the following :

1. In every row I want to determine the number of nonzero values, which I have been able to do using np.where.
2. I then want to determine the column labels that contribute to these non-zero values in each row. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888) If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Please also include your code where you were able to count the number of zeros per row, and provide expected output for how you want the final result to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count your non-zeros in each row you can use [`nonzero_count`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) from `numpy` package and perform the operation row-wise:

```
import numpy as np
df['non_zero_count'] = np.count_nonzero(df,axis=1)

>>> df

      1     2     3     4     5     6      7  non_zero_count
0  8122     0     0     0     0     0      0               1
1     0     0     0  3292     0  1313      0               2
2     0  8675     0     0     0     0      0               1
3     0     0  1910     0   213     0  12312               3
4     0     0     0     0  4010     0      0               1
5     0     0     0     0     0  1002      0               1
6     0     0     0     0     0     0   1278               1
```

Then you can get the columns where a row contains a non-zero value with `apply`, so be cautious here if you have a big dataset at hand:

```
df['non_zero_label'] = df.drop('non_zero_count',axis=1)\
    .apply(lambda r: r.index[r.ne(0)].to_list(), axis=1)
df


>>> df

      1     2     3     4     5     6      7  non_zero_count non_zero_label
0  8122     0     0     0     0     0      0               1            [1]
1     0     0     0  3292     0  1313      0               2         [4, 6]
2     0  8675     0     0     0     0      0               1            [2]
3     0     0  1910     0   213     0  12312               3      [3, 5, 7]
4     0     0     0     0  4010     0      0               1            [5]
5     0     0     0     0     0  1002      0               1            [6]
6     0     0     0     0     0     0   1278               1            [7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dataframe name is `df`:

```py
df[df != 0].stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

This returns a series with the column labels as index and the non-zero values, which for your example the output is:

```
1    8122.0
4    3292.0
2    8675.0
3    1910.0
5    4010.0
6    1002.0
7    1278.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [ 0,0,9],'y' : [-1,3,0],'z' : [0,1.1,3]},index=['a','b','c'])
df["non_zero_columns"] = df.where(df == 0, 
                                  other=df.apply(lambda x: x.name), 
                                  axis=1).where(df != 0, 
                                                other="").apply(lambda row: ''.join(row.values), axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
x  y    z non_zero_columns  non zero
a  0 -1  0.0                y         1
b  0  3  1.1               yz         2
c  9  0  3.0               xz         2
```

Apply that to your dataframe.

Another solution for the same dataframe would be:

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.apply(lambda x: x != 0)
df['Non_zero_columns'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(cols[x.values]), axis=1)
df['Length'] = df['Non_zero_columns'].str.len()
```

which produces:

```
  x      y      z Non_zero_columns  Length
a  False   True  False              [y]       1
b  False   True   True           [y, z]       2
c   True  False   True           [x, z]       2
```